# Using UWP created in Windows Template Studio into the Uno Platform

Tags: uwp, windows-template-studio, uno-platform

I am asking about the procedure of using the existing UWP app ant then include into the Uno Platform ?
Is it possible to create UWP in Windows Template Studio, or in Syncfusion, and than use the code into the Uno Platform?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the Uno Platform's document: [What does Uno not do](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/intro.html#what-does-uno-not-do), it mentions that **While the Uno Platform provides all the UWP APIs, a lot of those APIs are not implemented**. It means not all APIs in UWP are supported in Uno Platform. You can use the code in Uno Platform but some of the APIs in UWP might not work.